# Java don't allow to enter second string after int

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter string1: ");
    str1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter integer1: ");
    int1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter string2: ");
    str2 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered string1 is= " + str1 + ", integer1: " + int1 + " and string2:  " +str2);
```

And my app results:

```
Enter string1: A // I entered A
Enter integer1: 5 // I entered 5
Enter string2: You entered string1 is= A, integer1: 5 and string2:
```

As you see my app don't ask me for entering string2. If I change int and string2 positions so enter string2 before int it works but not work like that. What&where is my mistake?

Comment: You're true. I changed str2 = scan.next(); and it works. Thanks

Comment: nextLine() reads the rest of the line after the last thing you read e.g. the `int` value.